# Open in app the shared document

Tags: sharepoint-online, app, sharepoint-permissions

My Customer shared the Folder in SharePoint for me.
I have the access to this folder, I have the permissions for the file editing and uploading into this shared folder.

But I have no availability to open these **shared** documents in the App (Word or Excel):
[image: This is what I see in **shared** folder]

And this is the similar screen for **my** SharePoint Folder.

[image]

Could you help me and my Customer with this issue. I'm developing the complicated system to update some files using his master files so I need the full access to the files.

The problem is hard due I never worked with SharePoint before and Customer has not much knowledge about the sharing, rights, permissions etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could the customer see the option "Open in app"?

Try to ask your customer to give your full control to this folder.

1.Click manage access of this folder:

[image]

2.Then click advanced:

[image]

3.Then give you full control on this foler:

[image]

Comment: >> Could the customer see the option "Open in app"? 
- Yes.

Comment: Have you try to give full control on this folder? Besides, are there any policies that prevent opening files in the client app? Read here for more:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-from-unmanaged-devices

Comment: it works. Thanks!